# How to write this as a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I would like some help writing this as a regular expression since I know the basics but not sure how to translate it into RegEx.

```
"command:argname-argvalue:arg2name-arg2val!!END!SENDTO:IP.ADD.RE.SS"
```

Command: specific keyword that determines the action I must handle. Must be there.

Arguments: (shown there 2, but not limited to 2, as many as wanted) `argument name` and `argument value`, separated by a hyphen. At least one.

`!!END!` declares the end of the expression and must be there.

`SENDTO:000.000.000.000` optional argument and has to match `SENDTO:` and then a valid IP address.

I then want to store the command, argument name and argument value pairs and, if included, the user ip, in a Python implementation.

I know this sounds like homework but please guys I have now idea how to do this and I would expend hours in trying to learn advanced RegEx. If you could help me, I would be glad to receive your help.

Comment: if you can't handle the regexes, then there's no reason you can't use regular string-parsing methods. the format's simple(ish) enough as is. scan for a `:`, there's your command, scan for a bunch more `:`, there's your args. scan each arg chunk for a `-`, there's your name/value. stop when you hit `!!`, etc...

Comment: You need to provide us real, or at least real mock-ups of the samples of the data you want matched with the expression. It will improve the quality of this question, and the willingness of the community to assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about the following regex ?

```
[\w ?]+:\w+-\d+:\w+-\d+!!END!(\\\[)?\w+:\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b(\\\])?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/dWES0YpXZen1X_W1)

this match some sentence like following :

```
command:argname-123:arg2name-340234!!END!\[SENDTO:000.000.000.000\]
```

Comment: Ip addresses don't typically pad the quads in dotted-quad notation, so your `\d{3}` use won't match many ips - 10.1.1.10 for example. Have a look at "IP Addresses": http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html. You also missed where he said the `\[` and `\]` were for illustration and shouldn't be included - you should wrap that section in an optional group

Comment: That is, @Daenyth, thanks, please Kasra edit that point, what is optional is not the `[` but what is between. Thank you very much though and tell me when you re-edit that point there.